# Can't add <script src=".." to a Window created with window.open() .. document.write(9

Tags: javascript

I have a stupid problem I don't understand, googleing is very difficult, because I get 1000 trivial matches with window.open and script src=..

I do something like this:

```
myWin= open("", "displayWindow",   "status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=yes");
myWin.document.open();
myWin.document.write("<html><head><title>Test-Window");
myWin.document.write('</title>');
myWin.document.write("<script src='my.js'/>");
myWin.document.write('</head><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>');
myWin.document.close();
```

Every time I add the line:

```
myWin.document.write("<script src='my.js'/>");
```

the window left empty.

I tried it with something like:

var script = myWin.document.createElement('script');
...
but the same effect.

I think the browser interpretes the script end tag and breaks. but what can I do?

Thanks a lot for reading,

kind regards

Thomas

Comment: IMHO, `document.createElement('script');` should not throw the end script tag error, have you got anything that fires in console? is my.js loading ok on hard written html page?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to concatenate `</script>` end tag. For example like this:

```
myWin.document.write("<script src='my.js'></sc" + "ript>");
```